# inserting or updating a query parameter with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want every access to my page situated at `www.mysite.com/nouveauSite/shop.html` to be redirected to the same url with locale=fr added to the query string.

I can see 3 types of requests:

1. Url with no query string: `/nouveauSite/shop.html` should be rewritten to `/nouveauSite/shop.html?locale=fr`
2. Urls with a query string, but no `locale` parameter: `/nouveauSite/shop.html?foo=3` should be rewritten to `/nouveauSite/shop.html?locale=fr?foo=3`
3. Urls with a query string containing the `locale` parameter set to something other than `fr`: `/nouveauSite/shop.html?foo=3&locale=en` should be rewritten to `/nouveauSite/shop.html?locale=fr&foo=3`

Right now I only have number 2 working.
I am using this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !locale=
RewriteRule ^shop.html     /nouveauSite/shop.html?locale=fr [R,L,QSA]
```

I thought this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nouveauSite/shop.html
RewriteRule ^shop.html     /nouveauSite/shop.html?locale=fr [R,L]
```

would fix number 1, but it does not seem to work.

I don't know what to do for number 3.

Comment: To clarify, your `.htaccess` file would seem to be in the `/nouveauSite` subdirectory? `/shop.html?locale=fr?foo=3` - I assume you mean `/shop.html?locale=fr&foo=3`? Your first rule should "work" for #1 and #2, since these are really the same thing, ie. no `locale` parameter. Only #3 is a special case, but depending on how your app reads "duplicate" parameters then all 3 could be handled by a single rule. Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? How are you reading these URL parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 2 redirect rules in your .htaccess for this:

1. Check if `locale=` query parameter doesn't exist in query string, then simple add `locale=fr` with `QSA` flag to preserve original query string.
2. A bit more involved rule to check if `locale=` query parameter exists with anything other than `fr` value then we'll have to replace it with `locale=fr`

You can have these 2 redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# rule #1 when locale= doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nouveauSite/shop\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)locale= [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?locale=fr [R=302,L,QSA]

# rule #2 when locale= exists with anything other than fr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/nouveauSite/shop\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?locale=(?!fr(?:&|$))[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1locale=fr%2 [R=302,L]
```

I have kept `R=302` in these rules for testing purpose and you should change them to `R=301` afterwards to make it permanent redirect.

**Test Results with above rules**

```
curl -I 'localhost/nouveauSite/shop.html'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 05:38:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.11
Location: http://localhost/nouveauSite/shop.html?locale=fr
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1


curl -I 'localhost/nouveauSite/shop.html?foo=3'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 05:38:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.11
Location: http://localhost/nouveauSite/shop.html?locale=fr&foo=3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1


curl -I 'localhost/nouveauSite/shop.html?foo=3&locale=en'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 03 Nov 2020 05:40:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.46 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/7.4.11
Location: http://localhost/nouveauSite/shop.html?foo=3&locale=fr
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```